# Mean Equation Specification using rugarch in R

Tags: r, time-series, garch, volatility-forecasting

I fitted a GARCH(1,1) to my 4511 return observations using `rugarch` in R.

**Question:** Which of these two mean equation specifications does `rugarch` in R use for a GARCH(1,1) when a mean is considered?

- $r_{t} = c + \sigma_{t}\varepsilon \quad​$ where $\quad\varepsilon​ \sim i.i.d. N(0,\sigma^2)$
- $r_{t} = c + \varepsilon\quad​$ where $\quad\varepsilon = σ_{t}z$

Note: $z \sim i.i.d. N(0,\sigma^2)$.

I ask because sometimes in papers/books you see both styles and I have to know exactly which mean equation is used.

Comment: σ is element of Θ and Θ is a finite dimensional parameter space

Comment: Check out the $\LaTeX$ code used for the questions – not a big difference from your original code but looks nicer.

Comment: FYI, you can accept a satisfactory answer by clicking on the tick mark to the left. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour). Otherwise, you can ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The first one goes against the basic logic of GARCH which says that the additive error term in the model is a product of an $i.i.D(0,1)$ term (not $i.i.D(0,\sigma_t)$ term) $z_t$ multiplied by its conditional standard deviation $\sigma_t$, for some assumed distribution $D$ (e.g. normal or Student-$t$).

The second one is correct, provided the time indices are the same for each element except for $c$:
$r_t=c+\varepsilon_t=c+\sigma_t z_t$ where $z_t\sim i.i.D(0,1)$.